# Calls to all googletagmanger.com URLs fail

Tags: url, mx-linux, google

I've been updating code on a website that contains calls to googletagmanager.com for a couple of days now, but only just realised that it's wasn't really broken.  Turns out my MX Linux desktop simply refuses to connect any requests made to googletagmanager.com...

All browsers = fail

All plugins = disabled or removed

ping googletagmanger.com = success

httping https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-866896948 = fail "could not connect (Connection refused)"

Tested on 4 other computers = success

So it looks like it's something with my computer only because **calls to anyones googletagmanager URL fail, not just ones I maintain** for my own clients.  Any ideas what to look at next?

I'm running MX-21.3 "Wildflower"

Comment: Is it *only* tracking websites like googletagmanager.com? Because that's Google's user tracking, and I'll be honest, you're not losing much if that doesn't work, unless you're Google :) anyway, if it's only that, you seem to have set up some DNS-based ad-blocker on your MX linux.

Comment: @MarcusMüller As mentioned in my original post, I have no plugins installed on any of the 5 different browsers I've tested this on.  How would I check my local DNS settings?  I don't use it as a service on this workstation.  I don't know much about the underthehood stuff when it comes to Linux.

Comment: please use syntax for formatting text; it will increase legibility